# how to access the correct global variable in C?

Tags: c

lets say I have some global var GLOBAL in main.c, but my main.c has a #include "other.h". But other.h has global var GLOBAL too.

How do I let the compiler know which one I meant when I write GLOBAL in main. Is there a "this" keyword that I can use?

Comment: One good example of why variables are not defined in header files. :-)

Comment: You should always *define* global variables in .c files (this allocates space for them), and *declare* them using `extern` in .h files (this makes them visible to other modules).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm assuming you've defined the variable in the program, and not in the preprocessor using a #define.

If you want to refer to the one created in the main.c, you just type global. To refer to those in your header file, use the keyword extern.

You'd be better declaring them as two seperate variable names though to be honest.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this just doesn't make a shread of sense to me. Especially the proposed use of `extern` to refer to a "variable in header file" (???)

Comment: "The keyword extern indicates that the actual storage and initial value of a variable, is stored elsewhere"

I've always done global variables in C like I want to refer to one defined in a header, it's declared as
    extern <type> variable
If I then want to create a variable local to the source file I'm writing with the same name, I simply create a new reference like so
    <type> variable
Why you'd want a global var in your main in the first place is beyond me, but this is what was asked for. Unfortunately, the capitalisation hints they've been #define d, making this whole question pointless

Answer (score 10):

You can't have two global variables with the same name in C program. C might allow multiple definitions in the same file scope through the *tentative definition* rule, but in any case all definitions will refer to *the same* variable. So, apparently your question is based on incorrect premise. There's no issue of "which one" here. You only have *one* variable.

For example, you can have a sequence of file-scope definitions in C translation unit

```
int i;
int i;
int i;
```

This is legal in C (as opposed to C++) and all these definitions are actually defining the same variable, not three different variables.

Of course, if one of the variables is defined as a local variable (if so, you have to state it in your question) (BTW, why is it called `GLOBAL` then?), then it will hide the name of the variable defined in the file scope (or any higher scope). In this case there's no way to access the hidden name in C. Rename the local variable to avoid hiding the global one.

What you mean by "other.h also has the variable" is not clear as well. What does "has" mean in this case? Is the variable *defined* in other.h? Or just *declared*? If it is just declared, then it doesn't really "have" it. If it is *defined* there... well, then the real question is: why are you defining variables in .h files?

Comment: GLOBAL is a global variable in both files, not a local varaible

Comment: I know. 95% of my answer is dedicated to the situation when both declarations are *global*. The reference to a local declaration is made as a side note.

Comment: Andrey, there is a way to access global variable, shadowed by local (let's say function scope) - re-declare it as `extern` at smaller scope

Answer (score 5):

You don't actually have two variables.  There is only one, you will either get a compiler (or linker) error if two modules declare the same global with the same name, or the compiler/linker will decide that you meant this to be redundant declarations of a single variable and merge them.

Answer (score 2):

Like others have mentioned, avoid using the same global variable/function names. Take the habit of prefixing them with the module name. I.e. MODULE1_state, MODULE2_state, etc.

If a global variable is only going to be used inside one source file, don't declare it in the matching header file. Instead, declare it at the top of the source file, and use the `static` keyword. Variables that need to be accessible to other modules need to be declared in the header file using the `extern` keyword. The same applies to global functions. It helps to maintain the same public/private discipline you'd normally use in an object-oriented language like C++, Java, C#, etc.

Example:

In module.h:

```
#ifndef MODULE_H /* Header guard */
#define MODULE_H

/* Declarations for entities that CAN be accessed by other modules,
   i.e. "public". */
extern int MOD_publicVariable;
extern void MOD_publicFunction(int arg);

#endif // MODULE_H
```

In module.c:

```
/* Definitions for entities that CAN be accessed by other modules,
   i.e. "public". */
int MOD_publicVariable = 42;
void MOD_publicFunction(int arg) {...}

/* Declarations for entities that CAN'T be accessed by other modules,
   i.e. "private". */
static double MOD_privateVariable = 12.34;
static void MOD_privateFunction1(void);
static void MOD_privateFunction2(void);

/* Function definitions. */
void MOD_privateFunction1(void) {
     int localVariable; /* This doesn't need the module prefix. */
     ....
}

void MOD_privateFunction2(void) {
     ....
}
```

The module prefix (MOD_) can be named directly after your module, or you can use an abbreviation. Experiment, and you'll eventually settle on a convention you like. Consistently using a prefix like this emulates the concept of a class/module/namespace in OO languages.

Make sure you know the difference between declaration vs. definition, and extern vs. static.

It irks me that C textbooks and courses either ignore or gloss over the art of multi-module programming.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that you should not generally make global variables accessible to other modules (i.e. make them "private"). If other modules need to access that variable, provide "public" "setter" and/or "getter" functions.

Comment: I like that you emphasise the difference between the *declaration* in the header, which simply says a variable of this name exists, and its *definition* in module.c, which actually allocates space for it (and which, confusingly, is also a declaration). I think this is one of several things the OP is tripping over.

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one definition per object module. The second one, if has the same content, will be ignored. If it differs, it will result in compiler error.

Comment: Technically, the standard requires one definition.  Appendix J does recognize a 'common extension' to the standard which is a horrible pun (or, at least, double entendre) because of Fortran COMMON definitions.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but why don't you try to avoid this kind of situations in the first place (and potentially the (over)use of globals)?

Answer (score 0):

First off, if this is an issue in the first place, you're using a crappy library and should rewrite/switch if possible. If you can't, you can do something like this:

other.h:

```
int GLOBAL;
//...other stuff
```

main.c

```
int GLOBAL;
#define GLOBAL OTHER_GLOBAL
#include "other.h"
#undef GLOBAL

int main(int argc,char** argv)
    {
    printf("%i %i",GLOBAL,OTHER_GLOBAL);
    getchar();
    return 0;
    }
```

however, if as the capitals imply, `GLOBAL` is `#define`ed, this might not work. (But it's worth a try anyway.)

Comment: Surely it would be easier and safer to just rename the `GLOBAL` in main.c to `MY_GLOBAL` or similar?  No hairy macros needed.