# "redeclaration of symbol with no linkage" when used on function scope

Tags: c, gcc

At file scope I can use a forward declaration of in initialized (static) variable.  There is a cyclic dependency. `s[0]` refers to the address of `count`. `count` refers to the count of items in `s`.

```
struct s { int *a; };

static int count;
int data1;
static struct s s[] = {
    &count, &data1 // , ... a lot more
};
static int count = sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]);
```

As shown in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124682/error-redeclaration-with-no-linkage) it is not possible to use the same construct at function (or block) scope.

```
void foo(void)
{
    static int count;
    static struct s s[] = {
        &count, &data1 // , ... a lot more
    };
    static int count = sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]);
}
```

It results in the error message

```
redeclaration of 'count' with no linkage.
```

The objective is to define a huge set of functions that have such tables. I am reluctant to define a second huge set of variables at file scope. Is there a way to define such variables at function scope?

**EDIT:** The code did not include one important thing. I missed the `static` before the initialized structure. This is essential since the array should not be built on each call.

Comment: How you are going to fix the scope yourself? Will next declaration overwrite previous one?

Comment: Why do you need to re-declare `count`?

Comment: On a meta level discussion, see XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @alk There is a desire to calculate the count at compile time instead of re-assigning the value at each function call.

Comment: @auselen So when I reword the question you would probably have an non-meta answer? I already mentioned why I want to have the variable local to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply not redefine it, assign the value to it instead:

```
void foo(void)
{
    static int count;
    struct s s[] = {
        &count, &data1 // , ... a lot more
    };
    count = sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]);
}
```

The difference should be negligible. Alternatively:

```
void foo(void)
{
    struct s s[] = {
        NULL, &data1 // , ... a lot more
    };
    static int count = sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]);
    s[0].a = &count;
}
```

The compiler may even be able to optimise that to initialize the `s[0].a` member to `&count` and eliminate the dead store of `NULL` to it.

Comment: I realized that the question was incomplete. Sorry for inconvenience.